# .htaccess rewrite rule modification

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a rule in the .htaccess file that makes a shorter URL:

```
RewriteRule ^job(.*)$ /include/myfile.incl.php?proj=$1 [NC,L]
```

So the final URL looks like:

```
mydomain.com/jobXXXXXX
```

I need to be able to add a token to the URL

```
mydomain.com/jobXXXXXX?token=123
```

How do I modify my rewrite rule to accept this value? Most of the time I won't have token present, but I need the rule overwrite to be flexible to accommodate it, in case I get it is the future.

Comment: Use the `QSA` flag ~ https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA

Comment: @Phil You should post it as answer and then get the question tagged as answerd

Comment: @Bob0t Meh, I don't like RTFM answers

Comment: @Phil haha x') you are the funny guy :P

Answer (score 3):

Try this rule (added `QSA(Query String Append)` flag for pass the query string):

```
RewriteRule ^job(.*)$ /include/myfile.incl.php?proj=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

result (simulated):

[image]

Comment: OK, if I just use QSA, without NC, L the error goes away, but I still do not get the token value from $_GET...

Comment: Make a var dump of the $_REQUEST superglobal to see where did it go

Comment: var_dump($_REQUEST);  produces: array(0){ }

Comment: @santa try to add "B" flag. i will help solve your problem, soon. (plz wait)

Comment: @santa im working this code.. http://puu.sh/a3dG8/812bff1bdc.png what version of apache is running?

Comment: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)

Comment: have you tried to upgrade apache version? i dont have apache 2.3 environment.